# Ways to open MahApps Flyout

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I've been working with MahApps and wanted to add a Flyout window. I assumed incorrectly that the logic was included with the control to detect when it should be opened closed.

What are some ways the community have been accomplishing this?

Currently I have added a rectangle to the grid on the far edge that uses mouse enter events to display the flyout and then the built in close arrow button.

What other neat ways are people doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <controls:FlyoutsControl Name="FlyoutControlSettings" Background="Beige">
        <controls:Flyout x:Name="yourMahAppFlyout"  Header="Flyout" Theme="Accent" Position="Left" Width="600" IsOpen="False" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3,0,3,3">
            <TextBlock FontSize="24">Hello World</TextBlock>

        </controls:Flyout>
    </controls:FlyoutsControl>
</controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

And then then code would look like this

```
    private void ToggleFlyoutSetting(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        yourMahAppFlyout.IsOpen = !yourMahAppFlyout.IsOpen;
    }
```